# I'm inexperienced with HTML and don't know why this function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-maps, syntax

So I'm currently using a google maps html api and I am trying to add this section of code, and when I do the map completely stops working. I am inexperienced with HTML but if you know of a syntax error or some other error causing this not to work please let me know what could be wrong.

```
function calc_gallons() {
        var averagempg = parseInt(document.getElementById("averagempg").value):
        var gallons = 0;
        var total = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
          total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        }
        total = (total / 1000)*0.621371;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
        if averagempg > 0 {
            gallons = total / averagempg
            alert('This trip requires' + gallons + 'gallon(s). Have safe travels!')
        }
        else {
            alert('Your average MPG must be a positive number in order to calculate the gallons required for this trip.')
        }
      }
```

Comment: Is there any console errors?

Comment: Yea I just started looking at that and there is a different one now that I have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement is missing parentheses around its condition. Does this code work?

```
function calc_gallons() {
        var averagempg = parseInt(document.getElementById("averagempg").value):
        var gallons = 0;
        var total = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
          total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        }
        total = (total / 1000)*0.621371;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
        if (averagempg > 0) {
            gallons = total / averagempg
            alert('This trip requires' + gallons + 'gallon(s). Have safe travels!')
        }
        else {
            alert('Your average MPG must be a positive number in order to calculate the gallons required for this trip.')
        }
      }
```

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much. I was coding so fast that I missed that. I also noticed that I put a colon instead of a semicolon for the first variable. now it doesn't break the page but the only problem is something to do with the event handler on the page being incorrectly written. still working on that one.

Comment: @GenGUMDROP No problem. Make sure to mark the answer as accepted so that others know you don't need any other answers! Please feel free to post another question if you can't figure out your next problem.